# Hazelcast: clear and putAll

Tags: java, hazelcast

Currently, I'm putting my list of elements on a hazelcast map by this way:

```java
provinciesMap.clear();
provincies.forEach(provincia -> provinciesMap.put(provincia.getCodi(), provincia.getNom()));
```

As you can see, I'm putting each element one by one.

Is there any more elegant way to `clear & putAll` my elements?

Comment: you can take a look at `IMap#putAll` method. you should convert the `provincies` collection to a local map (eg an HashMap) and pass it as a parameter to `putAll` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the newly created library on to the variable if you create it with a stream and collector:

```
provincesMap = provinces.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getCodi(), x -> x.getNom()));
```

Comment: I think `provinciesMap` is an instance of `IMap` which is a distributed data structure of Hazelcast.